# Django form handling wih fields inside divs

Tags: python, html, django, forms, user-input

I have form, that contains many div blocks and inputs **inside** them. I want to handle the result of submitting form, but when I watch for request, I see only csrfmiddlewaretoken and doesn't see data at all. Where there may be a problem?
Form example:

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
   <div class="home-blbox"><input type="number" id="valueInput"></div>
   <input type="submit value="Submit">
</form>
```

Code handling example:

```
def handle(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
    return render(.....)
```

An output is dict contains only csrf token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added *name* attribute in input tag. The *name* attribute specifies the name of an  element. The name attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted. Note: Only form elements with a *name* attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.

Update your html and add it like below.

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
   <div class="home-blbox"><input type="number" name="unumber" id="valueInput"></div>
   <input type="submit value="Submit">
</form>
```

After adding it you can get the input value in view using `request.POST.get('unumber')`. I hope this will help you. :)